# date-fns v2 parse time with a default timezone

Tags: date-fns

I have a string time value that is representing a central timezone value (Chicago time):

`const rawTime = "11:22 AM";`

Using date-fns v2.3.0 I am parsing a new Date object based on that:

`const time = parse(rawTime, "hh:mm aa", new Date(2019, 8, 23));`

I have a test that passes when I run it in Central time:

`expect(time).toStrictEqual(new Date("2019-09-23 11:22:00-05:00"));`

When I run the tests in UTC timezone it fails because it assumes it is a UTC time -- I understand why.

What I want is to know if there is a way to specify the "backupDate" value (the  `new Date(2019, 8, 23)` part of the parse) that would auto parse the time value with the timezone offset for the Central timezone..?  Or do I need to parse the time and then manipulate the data further using the date-fns-tz library?

I've tried a few different things but can't seem to get it to work, not a huge deal but would be nice to do if possible.

Relevant docs here - https://date-fns.org/v2.3.0/docs/parse#syntax)

Answer (score 0):

One way I've found to handle this - since I know the incoming time's timezone is Central time, I append the timezone info to the end of the raw time, then `parse` that new string adding in the timezone to the `formatString`.

```
const rawTime = "11:22 AM";
const rawTimeWithTz = rawTime + " -05:00"; // specify central timezone on the raw time
const time = parse(rawTimeWithTz, "hh:mm aa xxxxx", new Date(2019, 8, 23));

expect(time).toStrictEqual(new Date("2019-09-23 11:22:00-05:00"));
```

This doesn't 100% answer the original question, but it does give me the same behavior I was looking for.

Comment: also for the case of daylight savings time ➡ CDT UTC Offset: UTC -5, CST UTC Offset: UTC -6 